# initializer as opposed to assignment statement

Tags: java

I was reading about the `final` keyword in Java on Wikipedia here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)#Final_variables) and was a little confused by the first sentence. It says:

> A final variable can only be initialized once, either via an initializer or an assignment statement.

What is an "initializer" in this context? I googled and learned about an "initializer block" which is executed prior to constructors, but I don't think that's what this is referring to since an initializer block would still accomplish assignment with assignment statements. So what is an "initializer" which can do the same work as an assignment statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That Wikipedia paragraph is incredibly badly worded.  You can either initialise your final variable

- when you declare it,
- in an initialiser block after you declare it, outside of any method or constructor, or
- in a constructor.

You must pick only one of these places.  You can't initialise a final variable twice.

Answer (score 3):

The key word is **once**. You can do

```
final int i = 1;
```

**or**

```
final int i;
{
    i = 1;
}
```

Which is an initialization block; and yes - it will be copied (just as the first example is) into every constructor (including the default if none is explicitly provided).

Answer (score -1):

That *initializer* is not referring to an *initializer block*. It's referring to a field declaration that's accompanied with an initialization expression, as defined in the JLS [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3). For example,

```
class Example {
    final Foo theField = new Foo();
}
```

`theField` would be a field that has an initializer as opposed to

```
class Example {
    final Foo theField;
    public Example(Foo foo) {
        this.theField = foo; // a normal assignment
    }
}
```

---

The presence of an initializer influences whether a field can be considered a [constant variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4), a type of [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).